# FullScreenActivity broke my app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio gives the option to create a FullscreenActivity. So I chose to create it. Now my entire project is not compiling. I am not sure why. When I tried to undo, Android Studio says the following files have already been affected:

`attrs.xml` `style.xml` `manifest` and `colors`.

So far I have found the following new stuff that I don't understand

```
<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
</style>
```

Where `Widget.AppCompat` is in red.

The main issue seems to be that Gradle sync failed because it could not find "androidTestCompile".

Comment: are you using a testing framework? if not, you can safely delete all the androidTestCompile and testCompile lines from your `build.gradle`

Comment: please post your gradle file

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to the answer, but will definitely help you:

Use a Version Control Software so you can rollback:

> Version control is a system that records changes to a file or set of
>   files over time so that you can recall specific versions later. For
>   the examples in this book you will use software source code as the
>   files being version controlled, though in reality you can do this with
>   nearly any type of file on a computer.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html